# Change empty cell bgcolor onclick in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table

I'm just starting out with PHP, and I have a table with empty cells. I want to change the color of each cell when the user clicks it. I have the following code so far:

My HTML/ how I call the function:
`<td onclick="javascript: this.style.backgroundColor='<?php toggleColor(); ?>'"></td>`

My function:

```
function toggleColor(){
    global $bgcolor;
    if($bgcolor == 'white'){
        echo "#2E2E2E";
        $bgcolor = 'gray';
    }
    else if ($bgcolor == 'gray'){
        echo "#2E2E2E";
        $bgcolor = 'white';             
    }
    else {
        echo "#2E2E2E";
        $bgcolor = 'white';
    }
}
```

What happens now is that the cell `onclick` turns gray. But when I click it again, nothing happens.
Please help! Thank you!

Comment: PHP is a server-side language. You can't call php functions from JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Ya have mixed server side code (php) and client side code (js). The php code is only executed on the server before rendering the page. Once on the browser (Client side), only the javascript code would work. You should change the JavaScript code, now you are only setting the background color but you don't control how to toggle back to white on the client:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#my-table').on('click', function(){
           $(element).toggleClass('bg-grey');
       });
    });
</script>
<table id="my-table">
    <td onclick="toggleBackground(this)"></td>
</table>
```

Note: the code has not been tested, but ilustrates the way of doing it.

Comment: I changed part of this to "element.style.backgroundColor" for it to work. But, I still encounter the problem that it works for the first click, but doesn't the second time I click the cell.

Comment: I have edited the code in order to use JQuery, a JS framework for programming in client side. Using this library will help you if you don't have previous experience in programming in JS for web pages. 

You can use it by adding this tag in your HTML <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You cant call php function using javascript directly. SO you need to define php function in javascript. I have updated the js function as below.

```
  var bgcolor;
  function toggleColor(){

      if(bgcolor == 'white'){

        bgcolor = 'gray';
        return "#2E2E2E";
      }
      else if (bgcolor == 'gray') {

        bgcolor = 'white';             
        return "#2E2E2E";
      }
      else {
         bgcolor = 'white';
         return "#2E2E2E";

      }
   }
```